# PHP Destructor is not called

Tags: php

I'm Using PHP 5.4.12

I have two class

```
<?php

class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {
//..
}

$handler = new MySessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler,true);

?>
```

And

```
<?php
class MySession {
//..
function __destruct() {
     session_write_close();
     echo 'called';
    }
}
```

And with this code, MySession's destructor is never called.

```
<?php
require_once 'MySessionHandler.php';
include_once 'MySession.php';
$test = new MySession();
```

But with this code, "MySession" destructor is called ok

```
<?php
require_once 'MySessionHandler.php';
include_once 'MySession.php';

class Test {
    function __construct() {
        $test = new MySession();
    }
}
$obj = new Test();
```

I have tested session_set_save_handler($handler,true/false).
I need MySession's destructor to be called 'cause I have issues with session_write_close(); I have to call it explicitly or the session never will be written to the server.

any workaround about this? I have simplified the code to their roots, but the __destruct method is not called when should be.

Comment: See marshall answer. MySession Is a class not a function

Answer (score 3):

Dont depend on `__destruct`... [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php):

> When using objects as session save handlers, it is important to register the shutdown function with PHP to avoid unexpected side-effects from the way PHP internally destroys objects on shutdown and may prevent the write and close from being called. Typically you should register 'session_write_close' using the register_shutdown_function() function.

Answer (score 1):

In your case above, you need to instantiate the object:

```
$test = new MySession();
```

Answer (score 0):

by calling the `__destruct()` function itself
in my case `__destruct()` is not called  when working in child file came from different file location.

I think `__destruct()` can only work on a single file page.